# Splinting textBox.text and print it in label in asp.net using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an text box and I want split its text and print that splited text in different labels.
suppose I text box user writes **Ravi Bhushan** now I want spit it in two labels each after the space (In first label **Ravi** and in second label **Bhushan**. In ASP.net using c#

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = txtName.Text.ToString();
    char[] seperators = new char[] {' '};


    string[] splitedName = Name.Split(seperators);
    foreach (string s in splitedName)
    {
        //System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        lblFst.Text = s.ToString();
    }


}
```

If I use above code then in **LblFst** where I want to print **Ravi** it is printing **Bhushan**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // string Name = txtName.Text.ToString();
    //char[] seperators = new char[] {' '};


    string[] splitedName =  txtName.Text.Split(' ');
    lblFst.Text = splitedName[0];
    lblSecond.Text = splitedName[1];

}
```

To prevent XSS attack, you should encode the string before assigning them to label:

```
lblFst.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(splitedName[0]);
lblSecond.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(splitedName[1]);
```

Thanks to  [Michael Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127114/michael-liu) for pointing to this!